# Google Tag Manager Tracking a Form with Multiple Options

Tags: javascript, forms, google-tag-manager, tracking

I am trying to set up conversion tracking within GTM for a form that gives the user multiple options from a drop-down menu.

On click the user is given the following option:
A
B
C
D

Each option generates a new form (without the URL changing), the problem being that the successfully submit destination page is the same for each different form generated - /thank-you/.

There are no unique identifiers on the /thank-you/ page. However, when an option is selected such as B a unique ID is generated on the page containing the form.

My only thoughts for a trigger were to have a tag fire when the URL was equal to /thank-you/ and an ID on the previous page was equal XXX.

But as far as I know, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternate solution: use events, goal and GA segments (type - sequences).

Just create 4 events (A, B, C, D) and goal for `/thank-you/` page.

Comment: Hi Ms Easy

Thank you for your response, that will resolve the issue in Google Analytics. The only issue now is that these triggers are also sending conversions to Google Ads which cannot be segmented.

Comment: @JonathonD When URL changes to `/thank-you/`, page reloads?

Comment: Yes, the page reloads it is not being triggered by ajax. What were you thinking?

Comment: @JonathonD May be don't use page view of `/thank-you/` as trigger for successful submission of the form, but use standard trigger in GTM for forms or custom trigger for ajax which catches server response. And use IDs A, B, C, D in conditions for triggers.